# Progress Bar not Visible

Tags: c#, progress-bar

If I create a `ProgressBar` via the `ToolBox` and add the following line in my code:

```
progressBar1.value = 40;
```

I am able to view the progress bar when my application runs.

However, if I try to create one via my code, I am unable to view one - The progress bar is not visible. Here is my code:

```
ProgressBar progressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(168, 180);
progressBar1.Height = 650;
progressBar1.Width = 340;            
progressBar1.Minimum = 20;
progressBar1.Maximum = 100;            
progressBar1.Value = 49;    
progressBar1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: What framework are you using to create your app? WPF , WinForms? We don't have much to go on here :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Windows Forms then you must add it to your form like that:

```
this.Controls.Add(progressBar1);
```

If you are using WPF then you must do that:

```
this.Children.Add(progressBar1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the progressbar to your application window first.

Assuming you're using WPF creating the ProgressBar in your Window class:

```
this.Children.Add(progressBar1);
```